# ARKIT 2.0 Image Detection : can't find when image disappear with ARImageTrackingConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

In the new arkit 2.0 documentation, it explain: and can accurately track when images disappear from view (or reappear afterward)

How could I be notified that the image is no loger visible ?
I could not find the documentation about it.

Thankfully, Kevin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `ARImageAnchor` conforms to the `ARTrackable Protocol` which:

> is adopted by ARKit classes, such as the ARFaceAnchor class, that
>   represent moving objects in a scene.
>
> ARSCNView and ARSKView automatically hide the nodes for anchors whose
>   isTracked property is false.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/artrackable).

As such you can do something like this to check if your image is visible or not:

```
//--------------------------
//MARK: -  ARSessionDelegate
//--------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate{

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        //1. Enumerate Our Anchors To See If We Have Found Our Target Anchor
        for anchor in anchors{

            if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor, imageAnchor == targetAnchor{

                //2. If The ImageAnchor Is No Longer Tracked Then Handle The Event
                if !imageAnchor.isTracked{

                }else{


                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Whereby `targetAnchor` is simply an `ARImageAnchor` I have stored reference to as a `Global Variable.`

Hope it helps...

Comment: Nothing more memory efficient? Comparing it in every update seems a lot of processing

Answer (score 1):

I find it easiest to check if the node `isHidden` property within the `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)` method.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    if node.isHidden {
        print("Node is out of view")
    }
}
```

I can't speak to the performance of this vs the previous anchor listener technique.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 possible answers to your question though I'm not sure entirely which one will solve your problem based on the details provided so far:

1: Becoming the delegate of the AR Sceneview allows you to listens for anchor addition/updates/removal https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate

This is mostly clear from a lot of their provided sample code though and if you are adding nodes already, you must already be listening to at least some of these methods.

2: You may be simply needing to check if your camera is looking at the node at this moment whether it has been removed or not using by calling your renderer's `isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522647-isnode